# Determine if column is increasing or decreasing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have data table that has column `ORDER` that is supposed to indicate if the values are increasing or decreasing and another column `ORDER_BASIS`. However, data in `ORDER` is often incorrect at the first place so I am trying to determine the correct order using `ORDER_BASIS`.

Here's what the table looks like:

| ORDER | ORDER_BASIS |
| --- | --- |
| INCREASING | 8 |
| INCREASING | 16 |
| INCREASING | 12 |
| INCREASING | 5 |
| INCREASING | 1 |
| INCREASING | 1 |
| INCREASING | 10 |
| INCREASING | 16 |
| INCREASING | 16 |

I am trying to achieve this:

| ORDER | ORDER_BASIS | CORRECT_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INCREASING | 8 | INCREASING |
| INCREASING | 16 | INCREASING |
| INCREASING | 12 | DECREASING |
| INCREASING | 5 | DECREASING |
| INCREASING | 1 | DECREASING |
| INCREASING | 1 | DECREASING |
| INCREASING | 10 | INCREASING |
| INCREASING | 16 | INCREASING |
| INCREASING | 16 | INCREASING |

First column may use `ORDER` then the following rows should determine if it's increasing or decreasing. If value did not increase or decrease then remain with it's current status until there's a change in value.

My current logic uses LAG and LEAD:

```
SELECT
    LEAD (ORDER_BASIS, 1, 0) AS NEXT_BASIS,
    LAG (ORDER_BASIS, 1, 0) AS PREV_BASIS
FROM 
    DATA_TABLE
```

Then created a condition but cannot get it to work correctly

```
CASE 
    WHEN CAST(PREV_BASIS AS int) = 0  
         OR (CAST(PREV_BASIS AS int) >= CAST(ORDER_BASIS AS int) 
             AND CAST(NEXT_BASIS AS int) <= CAST(ORDER_BASIS AS int))   
        THEN ORDER_BASIS 
        ELSE 'OPPOSITE_DIRECTION' 
END AS CORRECT_ORDER
```

Using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Given that your requirement is based on the existing or natural order of the records, you should include a column that can be used to sort the results, either an auto-incrementing Id field or a DateTime2/Offset based column. This is especially important with LAG or LEAD sequential based logic.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question has no meaning unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your query has not any `order by` statement, the order of rows is totally random anytime,and can be different. so to solve this problem you need some column that you can guarantee the initial order of rows , then we can fix the issue :

```
select * , 
 case when ORDER_BASIS > LAG(ORDER_BASIS,1,-1) over (order by <the column>) 
    then 'INCREASING'
 case when ORDER_BASIS = LAG(ORDER_BASIS,1,-1) over (order by <the column>) 
   then 'No change'
 else 'DECREASING' end CORRECT_ORDER
from DATA_TABLE
```

Comment: This works! Massive thanks! I used OVER (PARTITION BY OTHER_COLUMNS ORDER BY TimeStamp) which results to the same order as I have sampled here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With sequential processing functions, like `LAG` and `LEAD` the sequence is the most important factor to maintain and is the one item that was left out of the original post. In SQL Server, window functions will operate on their own partition (grouping) and sort criteria, so when visually correlating the data it is important to use the same criteria in the external query as you do for the window functions.

> The following solution can be explored in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5e1ee/31

To validate your input conditions, run the query to output the `LAG` and `LEAD` results:

```
SELECT
  [Id],[Order]
  , LAG (ORDER_BASIS, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) AS PREV_BASIS
  , [Order_Basis]
  , LEAD (ORDER_BASIS, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) AS NEXT_BASIS
FROM DATA_TABLE;
```

| Id | Order | PREV_BASIS | Order_Basis | NEXT_BASIS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INCREASING | (null) | 8 | 16 |
| 2 | INCREASING | 8 | 16 | 12 |
| 3 | INCREASING | 16 | 12 | 5 |
| 4 | INCREASING | 12 | 5 | 1 |
| 5 | INCREASING | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | INCREASING | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 7 | INCREASING | 1 | 10 | 16 |
| 8 | INCREASING | 10 | 16 | 16 |
| 9 | INCREASING | 16 | 16 | (null) |

The next issue is that your attempted logic is using the `LAG` *AND* the `LEAD` values, which is not invalid, but is usually used to compute a value that either *smooths out the curve* or is trying to detect *spikes* or *Highs* and *Lows*.

> It is not necessary to do this via a CTE however, it simplifies the readability of the syntax for this discussion, within the CTE we can perform the Integer Casting as well, however in a production environment it might be optimal to store the `ORDER_BASIS` column as an Integer in the first place.

```
WITH Records as
(
  SELECT
    [Id],[Order]
    , CAST(LAG (ORDER_BASIS, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) AS INT) AS PREV_BASIS
    , CAST([Order_Basis] AS INT) AS [Order_Basis]
    , CAST(LEAD (ORDER_BASIS, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) AS INT) AS NEXT_BASIS
  FROM DATA_TABLE
)
SELECT
    [Id],[Order],PREV_BASIS,[Order_Basis],NEXT_BASIS
    ,CASE 
        WHEN NEXT_BASIS > ORDER_BASIS AND PREV_BASIS > ORDER_BASIS THEN 'LOW'
        WHEN NEXT_BASIS < ORDER_BASIS AND PREV_BASIS < ORDER_BASIS THEN 'HIGH'
        WHEN ISNULL(PREV_BASIS, ORDER_BASIS) = ORDER_BASIS THEN 'NO CHANGE'
        WHEN ISNULL(PREV_BASIS, ORDER_BASIS) >= ORDER_BASIS 
               AND ISNULL(NEXT_BASIS, ORDER_BASIS) <= ORDER_BASIS
          THEN 'DECREASING' 
        WHEN ISNULL(PREV_BASIS, ORDER_BASIS) <= ORDER_BASIS 
               AND ISNULL(NEXT_BASIS, ORDER_BASIS) >= ORDER_BASIS 
        THEN 'INCREASING' 
        ELSE 'INDETERMINATE'
    END AS CORRECT_ORDER
FROM Records
ORDER BY [Id];
```

| Id | Order | PREV_BASIS | Order_Basis | NEXT_BASIS | CORRECT_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INCREASING | (null) | 8 | 16 | NO CHANGE |
| 2 | INCREASING | 8 | 16 | 12 | HIGH |
| 3 | INCREASING | 16 | 12 | 5 | DECREASING |
| 4 | INCREASING | 12 | 5 | 1 | DECREASING |
| 5 | INCREASING | 5 | 1 | 1 | DECREASING |
| 6 | INCREASING | 1 | 1 | 10 | NO CHANGE |
| 7 | INCREASING | 1 | 10 | 16 | INCREASING |
| 8 | INCREASING | 10 | 16 | 16 | INCREASING |
| 9 | INCREASING | 16 | 16 | (null) | NO CHANGE |

*You could extend this by using a `LAG` comparison again to determine if the `NO CHANGE` in the middle of the above record set is in fact a low point over a longer period.*

If the `CORRECT ORDER` should only be a function of the previous record, then there is no need to use a `LEAD` evaluation at all:

```
WITH Records as
(
  SELECT
    [ID],[ORDER]
    , CAST(LAG (ORDER_BASIS, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) AS INT) AS PREV_BASIS
    , CAST([ORDER_BASIS] AS INT) AS [ORDER_BASIS]
  FROM DATA_TABLE
)
SELECT 
  [ID],[ORDER],[PREV_BASIS],[ORDER_BASIS]
  , CASE WHEN ORDER_BASIS < PREV_BASIS
           THEN 'DECREASING'
         WHEN ORDER_BASIS > PREV_BASIS
          THEN 'INCREASING'
         ELSE 'NO CHANGE' 
    END CORRECT_ORDER
FROM Records;
```

| ID | ORDER | PREV_BASIS | ORDER_BASIS | CORRECT_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INCREASING | (null) | 8 | NO CHANGE |
| 2 | INCREASING | 8 | 16 | INCREASING |
| 3 | INCREASING | 16 | 12 | DECREASING |
| 4 | INCREASING | 12 | 5 | DECREASING |
| 5 | INCREASING | 5 | 1 | DECREASING |
| 6 | INCREASING | 1 | 1 | NO CHANGE |
| 7 | INCREASING | 1 | 10 | INCREASING |
| 8 | INCREASING | 10 | 16 | INCREASING |
| 9 | INCREASING | 16 | 16 | NO CHANGE |